# Fragment isAdded() returns false on an already added Fragment

Tags: android, fragment, fragmenttransaction

I have this neat function:

```
private void addMapFragment(){
    if(!mapFragment.isAdded()){
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.mapContainer, mapFragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

I'm calling `addMapFragment()` in my activity's `onCreate()`. I then have a callback from a webrequest that calls `addMapMapFragment()`. The `isAdded()` method doesn't look useful at all since I'm getting a crash saying "Fragment already added: `MapFragment[...]`"

Any clue?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`FragmentTransactions` are committed **asynchronously**. Therefore, you need to call

```
getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
```

**before** you call

```
Fragment.isAdded();
```

That way, you can make sure that **everything is up to date**.

Comment: Thanks Philipp for the title edit for clarity. I'm not getting this crash anymore although I have a new issue with a NPE in FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions. I guess there's something I'm not doing quite right. I also made sure to run executePendingTransactions() on the UI Thread.

Answer (score 0):

Instead, check getSupportFragmentManager.findFragmentById() and see if you are getting the expected fragment back. If now you can add and commit.

Comment: The bummer with that solution is that it's relatively expensive.

Comment: @Laurent  Not actually, `getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();` will force everything to be executed in Main thread synchronously. Which is much worse than `getSupportFragmentManager.findFragmentById()`.